# MySQL query to select ENUM('M', 'F') as 'Male' or 'Female'

Tags: mysql, sql

My field is an ENUM for gender and stores 'M' or 'F' but is there a way to select the field as 'Male' or 'Female' based on the value?

Comment: You can use the `case...when...then...else...end` construct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT IF(gender='M','Male', 'Female') AS Gender
```

Comment: @BadHorsie:) But remember using `if` in such a scenario would have performance bottleneck.

Comment: Is `IF` any more of a performance issue than `CASE`? And surely in this case using either is negligible?

Comment: I always handle this type of things in PHP. I think there isn't much difference between IF and CASE. Whether this is something that's going to affect your app's performance, you should discover by measuring rather than guessing.

Comment: I am only performing this operation on a single row so there is no performance worry.

Comment: I think the only downside is that you have to hard code male and Female

Answer (score 5):

You can make a case for it:

```
SELECT CASE enum_field 
WHEN 'M' THEN 'Male' 
WHEN 'F' THEN 'Female' 
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use following query to do so.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN field = 'M' THEN 'MALE'
            WHEN field = 'F' THEN 'FEMALE'
       END) AS sex
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE` statement, something like:

```
SELECT CASE FieldName WHEN 'M' THEN 'Male' ELSE 'Female' END
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

A different technique

```
select replace(replace(column,'M','Male'),'F','Female') from table
```